# Htc one A9 firmware flashing problem

Tags: rom-flashing, htc

Htc one a9 (model: 2PQ9100) see the error below i'm facing please help me i am very upset

C:\adb>fastboot oem rebootRUU
...
OKAY [ 0.047s]
finished. total time: 0.048s

C:\adb>fastboot flash zip firmware.zip
target reported max download size of 1166400000 bytes
Invalid sparse file format at header magi
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 617001178 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
sending sparse 'zip' (1139061 KB)...
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 617001178 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
error: write_sparse_skip_chunk: don't care size 617001178 is not a multiple of the block size 4096
OKAY [ 53.554s]
writing 'zip'...
(bootloader) HOSD CL#853511
(bootloader) ERR lzipv2_init : Cannot open file /dev/fastboot_download_z
(bootloader) EOonp
(bootloader) ERR [SD_UPDATE_ERR] update_fb_ZIP_buf: can not find ZIP hea
(bootloader) der
(bootloader) ERR [SD_UPDATE_ERR] sddownload failed: 22
(bootloader) ERR Update zip file failed.
(bootloader) ERR ZIP ERROR, exit read zip loop
(bootloader) ERR ZIP signature checking failed...
(bootloader) Update zip file OK
(bootloader) ERR ZIP ERROR CODE, 22
(bootloader) end@Done
FAILED (remote: 22 RU_HEADER_ERROR )
finished. total time: 91.572s

Comment: Is your bootloader locked?

Comment: ye its locked and S on.     i aslo use the match Cid HTC__J15 and version is also not down it upper than previous.

Comment: Is fastboot up to date? Also what type of OS is your computer using?

Comment: sir my software of mobile is not working only htc logo appear on white (as power on) screen then hide after few seconds. i am using windows laptop window 10.

Comment: i tried all  adb, fastboot applications all result's are same

Comment: Htc has fastboot bineries on there developers site have you tried those? Oh your .zip file is most likely corrupt with that error 22... `"22 RU_HEADER_ERROR: something wrong with your zip; check md5 of download"`

Comment: i don't have too much knowledge about it i tried so many zip and ruu.exe file but none of them work,, PLEASE give me correct one link that i will do. Ask me if you need any info about HTC ONE A9 to installing stockroom on it.

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct `MID, CID and version-main` and that it matches the ruu.zip. you can get that info from `fastboot getvar` command. Her is a bunch of ruu's for your device make sure you get the correct `MID, CID and version-main` from your device and that it matches the ruu.zip. 
https://forum.xda-developers.com/one-a9/general/wip-ruu-htc-one-a9-t3240344

Here is htc_fastboot version:

https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347805953 if successful or whatever I will/can write up an answer to your question and how to do it.

Comment: i do it with match MID, CID and main version of it also same HIA_AERO_UHL  with this room (2.17.401.2 RUU HTC Europe
modelid: 2PQ910000
cidnum: HTC__001
cidnum: HTC__034
cidnum: HTC__J15 (for my device)
cidnum: HTC__M27
cidnum: HTC__A07
cidnum: HTC__016
cidnum: HTC__002)

Comment: Tell me what should i do now HELP ME PLEASE

Comment: Use the command `fastboot getvar all` edit out the 

(Bootloader) serialno:
(bootloader) imei: 
(bootloader) mei:

Then edit your post adding the rest of the information from the output and i will give you an answer.